# Prove that a function $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow \Bbb{Q}$ is injective.

Tags: functions

How do I prove that a function $f$ is injective knowing that $ f : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}$ is defined such that

1.) $f(2n) = \frac{1}{f(n)+1}$ and

2.) $f(2n + 1 ) = f(n)+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}?$

I forgot to mention that $f(0)=0$

Comment: I assume that $\mathbb N$ is the positive integers. Under this definition, $f(0)$ does cannot be a rational number.

Comment: Or do you know what $f(0)$ is? If not, how do we find $f(1)?$

Comment: If $f(1)=0$ then $f(2)=1$ and $f(3)=1$.

Comment: is there another way to prove that it is injective?